# Is there a way to add more than one hyperlink in an excel cell in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I have an excel sheet where one column consist of comma seprated hyperlinks. However, I am unable to see a way to insert more that one hyperlinks in an excel cell. Is there a workaeround this?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind not splitting the links into 2 cells?

Comment: The client wants it that way, a comma seprated list of hyperlinks, all in one cell. I know it is ugly, but this is exactly which is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without an ugly kludge, and I would not advise that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Hyperlink is applied to the entire cell, therefore you can't hyperlink a cell to more than one address.

Workaround suggestion (not that I have an idea of why would you need comma-seperated hyperlinks in a single excel cell, but anyhow...):
Write a VBA script that performs the required functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure you could do this in VBA. You'd have to have a way to trap which link was clicked on, and there is no XY control on the spreadsheet itself, only on forms. The only thing I could figure is if when the cell is clicked on a userform pops up asking which link the user would like to open. But you might as well have the links in 2 separate cells if you do that.

Comment: I  was thinking more towards the Text Selection, but, you know, implementing a strange feature requires strange thinking.